# could not parse as a chaincode install package: did not find a code package inside the package external chaincode

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, hyperledger-chaincode

I have setup a Two node Kubernetes network, Installed hlf-operator. Created 2 organisations network with channel "mychannel" and external chain code "mycc". Now I want to create a new channel "mychanneltwo" and install new chaincode "mycctwo" on that using hlf operator. Can anybody help me here. Thanks in advance

- tried to generate new channel
- made peers join them
- tried to install chaincode on peers